# How delete a rectangle created with Canvas?

Tags: delphi, tcanvas

I have a rectangle that is drawed in a `TPaintBox` component using my mouse.
So, how delete this rectangle (totaly) from my application after "**mouse up event**" of `TPaintBox`?

[image]

Any suggestion will welcome.

Here is my code that draw this rectangle:

```
private
    FSelecting: Boolean;
    FSelection: TRect;
  end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FSelection.Left := X;
  FSelection.Top := Y;
  FSelecting := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FSelecting then
  begin
    FSelection.Right := X;
    FSelection.Bottom := Y;
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FSelecting := False;
  FSelection.Right := X;
  FSelection.Bottom := Y;
  PaintBox1.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Rectangle(FSelection);
end;
```

Comment: Save the area before drawing the rectangle, and restore it when you want it back the way it was.

Comment: Or, just redraw what was previously drawn in that spot, instead of saving the previous drawing.

Comment: Why are you using a solid red box to select something, instead of using a transparent box with a border around it? Do you want the user to see what is being selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete a drawing, you have to draw something else over top of it.

In the code you have shown, you can simply set `FSelection` to an empty 0x0 rectangle and `Invalidate()` the `PaintBox` again.  Its normal picture will be drawn, and you won't draw a rectangle on top of it.

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then
  begin
    FSelection := Rect(X, Y, X, Y);
    FSelecting := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FSelecting then
  begin
    FSelection.Right := X;
    FSelection.Bottom := Y;
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if (Button = mbLeft) and FSelecting then
  begin
    FSelecting := False;
    FSelection := Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //...
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Rectangle(FSelection);
end;
```

Or, assuming you need to remember the selected rectangle for use with other things, then simply don't draw the selected rectangle onto the `PaintBox` when `FSelecting` is false.

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then
  begin
    FSelection := Rect(X, Y, X, Y);
    FSelecting := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FSelecting then
  begin
    FSelection.Right := X;
    FSelection.Bottom := Y;
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if (Button = mbLeft) and FSelecting then
  begin
    FSelecting := False;
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //...
  if FSelecting then
  begin
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Rectangle(FSelection);
  end;
end;
```

Either way, for good measure, you should draw the rectangle transparent with a dotted border so the user can see what they are selecting without being too intrusive:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //...
  if FSelecting then
  begin
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Style := psDot;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Rectangle(FSelection);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help me.